# Password in the header is unencrypted via POST, how can it be secure?

Tags: security, post, https, passwords

Recently I have just noticed a problem of my internet banking service.

When I use Chrome Inspect to check the POST request, in the Form Data section, the password I entered is totally unencrypted. I just fear that someone fetch the header can see my userid and password directly.

However, my friend told me that, as it use HTTPS, only the sender and receiver can see the data in the POST method, thus the password is still secure. Is that correct?

Comment: The https protocol uses ssl encryption to encrypt _all_ data exchanged between client and server, _except_ for protocol specific details. Data in http headers is completely encrypted. Obviously your browser is able to see the details, since it is the client initiating the encryption. That does _not_ mean that the whole communication is secure, there are many details to be considered here. But the immediate answer to your question is: a password sent inside the http header is protected by encrption.

Answer (score 1):

Yes your friend is correct, data sent over a HTTPS/SSL connection is encrypted. Not only is this the standard way to pass sensitive information, it is the only way a website can set up a secure connection.

Other measures like encryption with JavaScript cannot help against a ManInTheMiddle attack, because the listener can alter or just remove the JavaScript before it reaches your browser. HTTPS on the other side works, because the Browser has a built in list of root certificates, which can be used to validate the SSL certificate of the website.